# How to merge data frames in pandas that have some columns in common and some not without losing any data

Tags: python, pandas

For example, if I had

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(8, 3)), columns=list('BCD'))
    display(df,df1)
        A   B   C   D
    0   63  16  89  55
    1   17  29  81  17
    2   88  82  9   64
        B   C   D
    0   21  38  36
    1   54  88  80
    2   44  53  53
    3   24  58  29

        A.  B.  C.  D
    0.  63. 16. 89. 55
    1.  17  29. 81. 17
    2.  88  82  9   64
    3. NAN. 21  38  36
    4. NAN. 54  88  80
    5. NAN  44  53  53
    6. NAN. 24  58  29
```

Is this possible?? I have about 25 data frames, all organized by ascending dates (the columns) and containing data for different airports (the indexes) for how many times a plane has ascended at each airport on each day. To reiterate, aiport names are the rows and dates are columns. The problem is, every data frame, containing 7 days, has a different number of airport names because some weeks some airports are inactive, and some weeks they're not. For that reason, it is really hard to merge them all together into a dataframe because each one has a lot of airports in common, but not necessarily in the exact same position (column number). Is there anyway to merge them so that NANs appear in the dates that the airports are inactive, and so that the rows of airport names are never duplicates? Sorry it is so hard to explain, thank you!!

Comment: To clarify, it sounds like you want to use pd.concat (vertically stack dataframes on top of each other and NOT pd.merge, which is a horizontal merge on a common key). Thus, since Airports are in the rows, it shouldn't matter if they out of order or are missing some and you can keep NaN values and/or remove duplicates. Is what you mean that the column DATES are out of order and/or the DATES don't always have 7 days. The sample you have provided is obviously just sample data, but it doesn't seem like the problem you are describing is lining up with what might be happening.

Comment: The reason that I don't want to vertically stack the data is that I want the airport names to be a continuous row along ascending dates (columns). For example, if there are 600 total airports (rows) in the final dataframe, I want ascending dates as columns to tell me how many ascensions happened in the airport per day since my end goal is to make a graph of airplane ascensions vs time by airport. The dates are in order. At the end of the day, I would want a data frame with those same 600 rows, but 25 weeks of columns.

Comment: I think that there is incomplete information without looking at the actual data, or if you can adjust values / names of the actual data. Once, you do that, share the desired output. The problem with randomly generating random integers is that it is quite different that having somewhat consistent airport names and dates.

Comment: probably want `update`, if the airports are the Index labels. That can add new rows and columns. But if things conflict you'll need to determine whether the new or old value gets precedence

Comment: After reading the explanation of your question and the comments, I thought it wouldn't be possible if I converted the wide format data to long format data, then combined the long format vertically for 25 weeks, then converted to wide format at the end. If you want to get a quick answer, you need to present specific data.